# Django: page not found 404 error when doing a post request

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a model where I am using two foreign keys. One of them is the logged-in user and the other is for inheriting the post. But post foreign key is not working or not saving into the database but it should save the particular post chosen by the user or with pk.

This is my models.py:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    b_price =  models..ManyToManyField(price, related_name='b_price',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True, default='')
    approved_price = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pay = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    mode = models.CharField(max_length=30 ,default='')

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

This is my views.py:

```
class booking_approve(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    form_class = forms.booking_form
    model = Booking
    template_name = "confirm_booking.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("Loader:post")

def form_valid(self, form):
    booking = get_object_or_404(Booking, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    print(form.cleaned_data)
    bk = form.save(commit=False)
    bk.user = self.request.user
    bk.save()
    bk.b_price.add(booking)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is my urls.py:

```
path('confirm_booking/<int:pk>/booking',views.booking_approve.as_view(), name="booking_approve"),
```

This is the HTML page where I pass the pk:

```
{% for loader_post in request.user.Loader.all %}
  {% for price in loader_post.prices.all %}


    {{loader_post.image_of_load.url }}
    Post id : {{loader_post.id }}
    Driver offer : {{price.driver_price }}
    Offer by : {{price.driver_name }}
    <a style="margin-right:20px;" href="{% url 'Loader:booking_remove' price.id %}"></a>
    <a href="{% url 'Loader:booking_approve' pk=price.pk %}"><</a>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %} {% endfor %} {% endblock content %}
```

This is my post pic. When I click on the tick button, the next form will appear but it should also take the id of the post but it won't.

[image: my post]

This the pk's error:

[image: error page]

Comment: does print() statement inside def form_valid() is printing your posted data?

Comment: no sir...nothing happen

Comment: try replacing createView with FormView

Comment: nothing happened ...same error

Comment: try replacing classBasedView to functionBasedView. Because i cant find error in code given above.

Comment: Your error is "No Booking matches the given query", So I'd double check your db has or does not have a Booking object with pk of 6.